# Does EclipseLink store ordered entity List incorrect?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have entity named Test1, it has 2 fields id and name.

I put about 1000 entity Test1 into a ArrayList with first entity has id = 1, second entity has id = 2, and so on... to 1000.

I use EclipseLink 2.4 provider to communication Postgresql database.

When I store List into database using following code:

```
EntityManager em;
List<Test1> list = new ArrayList<Test1>();
//populate data into list
for(Test1 test1 : list){
    em.merge(test1);
}
```

When I check database, the rows is not ordered as expected. The first row does not have id = 1, and the second row does not have id = 2 and so on...

What's wrong with EclipseLink or I got mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you wrote, you cannot be sure who is responsible for that: either your DB / DB client (when you check the order), or the EcliplseLink. Anyway, if you want a certain order for your JPA operations, you should use `EntityManager.flush()` in order to hit the DB, otherwise the persistence provider can decide when and in which order to flush its query cache. Also, if you want a certain order in your client, you should sort the results, as some databases (like MySQL) do not guarantee that the rows are returned in the same order in which they have been inserted.

Comment: Thank you for quick response! I have checked it and add em.flush() when store data. The result is correct as expected. Thank you again and good luck to you!

Comment: how to mark your answer? I don't see where to do that.

Comment: Please **don't flush** in a tight loop, this is terrible for performance. If you can tell us what you want to achieve (Like retrieving those entities into a particular order) we could come up with better advice.

Comment: I have 1 ordered List and I want to put it into database using JPA. The result that I expected all row in database are ordered.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends, depends on what?

Depends if the List has been marked with @OrderColumn annotation, default is not store the order of the list, but it depends on your model an eclipselink can be configured to store order and be the responsible for the correct update of that field.

Also use OrderColumn could be a hit in the performance so use with caution